# Why does a simple for loop make my computer run slow?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

It seems as though every time I try to run this code my computer starts freezing up. Am I doing something wrong here? My goal is to make a simple Sigma Notation program.

```
function sigmaNotation(n){
    let counter = 0
    for(let i = 1; i <=n; n++){
      counter = i * (i + 1)


    }
  }

  sigmaNotation(7)enter code here
```

Comment: Maybe its because I have n++ in the for loop as oppose to i++. Let me see if that's the problem.

Comment: Do you ever change the value of i? What conditions do you expect will cause this loop to terminate?

Comment: you are not changing the value of i.

Comment: Yep, you spotted the error! @VikingGlen has a good explanation of why

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, if your computer freezes during execution, you likely have a loop with no means of termination (as mason brought up).  When writing code, or anything else for that matter, what we see in our head isn't always what our fingers type.  To help prevent this, if possible and until you're satisfied the code is working, include some means that allows you to see the internal workings.  As a generic example,  you could include something like:

```
counter = i * (i + 1); console.log(counter, i);
```

I prefer to put "console.log( ... )" statements that are there temporarily on the same line as the variables I'm verifying.  If the code has thousands of lines, it's much easier to keep track of just exactly what I'm doing if checks are on the same line as what they're checking.